# Spring Boot: Read 'application.properties' file from a different path

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, application.properties

I want to be able to read the 'application.properties' file from a different path than '`/src/main/java/resources/application.properties`', which is the path assigned by SpringBoot.

For example, look for it in the following path: '`/user/demo/myAppProperties/application.properties`'

I also tried with `<exclude>**/application.properties</exclude>` in my pom.xml, but it gives me an error.

I already tried with `@PropertySource`.

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("file:/user/demo/myApplicationProperties/application.properties")
public class DemoApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApp.class, args);
    }
```

But when I do the tests with the .JAR of the application and modifying the `.properties` of my path, for example deleting the driver from the database, it continues to load the `.properties` of the project.

It can be done with the command line with the following flag: '`--spring.config.location=file:`', I want to do the same, but without using that flag when executing my .JAR.

I am using maven and pom.xml

I hope someone can help me, thank you very much. And I hope I explained myself well.

Comment: this might help: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar#load-config-programatically-1

Comment: I already tried it, but still get the same result, it takes the .properties of the project. Thank you very much!

Comment: The obvious solution would be to not put application.properties that you don't want inside the jar in the first place. What exactly is the problem that you are trying to solve?